# Laravel working with belongsToMany and extra fields

Tags: php, laravel, pivot, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to save a simple `belongsToMany` relation into my database. First, my table:

```
    Schema::create('user_activity_log', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('activity_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('log_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('sets');
        $table->unsignedInteger('reps');
        $table->primary(['activity_id', 'log_id']);

        $table->foreign('activity_id')->references('id')->on('user_activities')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->foreign('log_id')->references('id')->on('user_logs')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

My `Log` and `Activity` models have these relations:

Log:

```
public function activities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Activity::class, 'user_activity_log', 'log_id', 'activity_id')->withPivot(['sets', 'reps']);
}
```

Activity:

```
public function logs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Log::class, 'user_activity_log', 'activity_id', 'log_id')->withPivot(['sets', 'reps']);
}
```

And in both models I am using:

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

When adding a new activity to an existing log, in my store method I am doing simply this:

```
$log->activities()->syncWithoutDetaching([$request->input('activity_id'), ['sets' => $request->input('sets'), 'reps' => $request->input('reps')]]);
```

I am getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'sets' doesn't have a default value 

insert into `user_activity_log` (`activity_id`, `log_id`) values (3, 2)
```

I cannot figure out why it is not saving the `sets` and `reps`. When I `dd()` the `$request` values, they are there. And my `$log` is also there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue in calling `syncWithoutDetaching`.

Your data must be an associative array where the keys are the IDs and values are data.

In your code, you used an indexed array instead of an associative array, where the first index is id and the second index is data, but it must be an associative array where the key is `activity_id`, and the value of that key must be an associative array containing `sets` and `reps`.

```php
$log->activities()->syncWithoutDetaching([
    $request->input('activity_id') => [
        'sets' => $request->input('sets'),
        'reps' => $request->input('reps')
    ]
]);
```